# Manejo de struct como parametro en c

Tags: c, linux, lista, shell

mi duda es la siguiente:
Si yo tengo un struct tal que así:

```
struct listas{
 list command_list;
 list_mem memory_list;
};
```

que contiene 2 listas enlazadas de distinto tipo. Como parametro en las funciones de mi programa debo pasarle `struct listas *listas` y accedo a la lista que quiero dentro de la funcion con `listas->command_list` (por ejemplo). Mi problema viene a la hora de llamar a una funcion que tenga ese parametro y querer pasarle solo una lista tal que asi:

```
int insert(struct listas *listas, void *dato){
//pasos para insertar en la lista un dato
}
```

Ahora al querer llamar a la funcion insert me encuentro con que no puedo hacer esto:

```
int dato = 3;
insert(listas->command_list, dato);
```

Ya que me dice que el parametro que le tengo que pasar es un struct y no una lista en si.
Como deberia hacer para llamar a la funcion insert queriendole pasar una lista?

Gracias!

Comment: Se me ocurre que en lugar de un struct como tal, definas tu propio tipo. Se puede utilizar `typedef` para generar un tipo basado en una estructura. Luego cuando vayas a utilizar una variable la declaras con ese tipo. Si quieres una lista, puedes definir un array de ese tipo.

Comment: Has declarado que la función deba recibir un parámetro de tipo `struct listas*`, así que eso es lo que espera que le pases (una estructura). Si lo que querías era pasarle una sola de sus listas, deberías haber declardo su parámetro de tipo `list`, o de tipo `list_mem`, según corresponda. O bien de tipo `list*` si quieres pasarlo por referencia (pero en ese caso la llamada sería `insert(&listas->command_list, dato)`)

Comment: @abulafia El problema es que a veces al insert quiero pasarle list y otras list_mem, no me sirve pasarle solo un tipo de lista por parametro por eso.